# Getting Locale variant for simplified chinese

Tags: android, locale

How can I get simplified chinese description (简体)? From the available locale `Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE`, no method seems to return this description:

- `getDisplayLanguage()` returns the correct language name, but without the variant.
- `getDisplayName()` returns the correct language name and country, but also without the variant.
- `getDisplayVariant()` returns an empty string.

I've also tried to build a new `Locale` using the different constructors, also to no avail.

```
new Locale("zh", "CN");
new Locale("zh", "CN", "Hans");
```

I've checked the [Android source code for `LocalePicker`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java) and I've concluded that it is [loaded from the resources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/res/values/arrays.xml) (`special_locale_codes` and `special_locale_names`).

Any solutions besides having to hardcode/include this string in my resources?

Comment: Solved it. Was a fun problem. :)

Comment: @Drakes You wish! Just joking, nice try though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me explain my process on how I tackled this. First, I found this block of code in [LocalePicker.java](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/sources/android-16/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java)

```
private static String getDisplayName(Locale l, String[] specialLocaleCodes, String[] specialLocaleNames) {
    String code = l.toString();

    for (int i = 0; i < specialLocaleCodes.length; i++) {
        if (specialLocaleCodes[i].equals(code)) {
            return specialLocaleNames[i];
        }
    }
    return l.getDisplayName(l);
}
```

which takes in a `Locale` as you already know. Then it tries to find the locale code in the `specialLocaleCodes` string array. The `specialLocaleNames` you are seeking are obtained from [arrays.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/res/values/arrays.xml) as you've helpfully stated:

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="special_locale_codes">
    <item>ar_EG</item>
    <item>zh_CN</item>
    <item>zh_TW</item>
</string-array>
```

and the corresponding languages

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="special_locale_names">
    <item>العربية</item>
    <item>中文 (简体)</item>
    <item>中文 (繁體)</item>
</string-array>
```

Notice the code with the simplified Chinese is *zh_CN* and the last two characters are capitalized.

However,

```
Locale locale = new Locale("zh_CN");
System.out.println("Locale: " + locale);
```

prints

> Locale: zh_cn

Notice the lower case. So there is no way `specialLocaleCodes[i].equals(code)` will return true. So then I poked around [Locale.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Locale.java.html) and, long story short, we can bypass that case-changing jumble by doing this (and you MUST keep the 3rd parameter as an empty string for this to work):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN", "");
System.out.println("Locale: " + locale);
```

Prints

> Locale: zh_CN

With this you should be able to do this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN", "");
System.out.println("Name:" + locale.getDisplayName(locale));
```

Upon further inspection on Kitkat using this (thank you Andrew!)

```
int specialLocaleNamesId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("special_locale_names", "array", "android");
String[] specialLocaleNames = Resources.getSystem().getStringArray(specialLocaleNamesId);
```

it was possible to print out

> العربية,中文 (简体),中文 (繁體)

as expected. However, something in Kitkat is still preventing the correct string to display. Frustrating.

---

However, in [Lollipop 5.0+](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag(java.lang.String)) and Java 1.7 this works using `forLanguageTag()` in Locale.

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-Hans");
System.out.println("getDisplayName:" + locale.getDisplayName(locale));
System.out.println("getDisplayLanguage:" + locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
```

which prints

> getDisplayName:中文 (简体中文)
>   getDisplayLanguage:中文

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't work in Android 4.1: `Locale is 中文 (中国)`. +1 for the effort though :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that "com.android.internal.R" is vendor specific. I'm trying to get the contents of `String[] specialLocaleNames = resources.getStringArray(R.array.special_locale_names); ` from someone. That would show what a phone actually has stored in there.

Comment: Or could definitely change from one Android version to another. Which version did you test this in?

Comment: In fact I've looked that as well. Problem is there's no [`Locale.forLanguageTag(String)` in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html). And Android is Java 6.

Comment: You should keep your previous answer, and add to it instead of replacing it :)

Comment: Lollipop has support for `Local.forLanguageTag()`, Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: If so it should be listed in the documentation with the API level where it became available, and I cannot see anything. You didn't link me to any Locale class documentation. Any way I'm only interested in 4.1.

Comment: From API 21: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag(java.lang.String) Apologies, the link is labelled "Lollipop 5.0+" in my post. The strings are there, just darn near impossible to get at indirectly in Kitkat. I feel defeated. Apologies.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. No need to apologize, and feel happy man, you will get the bounty :D

Answer (score 1):

You could probably access the android internal resource: `com.android.internal.R.array.special_locale_names` the same way it's done in [`LocalePicker`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java#93):

```
final Resources resources = context.getResources();
final String[] specialLocaleNames = resources.getStringArray(com.android.internal.R.array.special_locale_names);
```

**But** it's probably safer to use your own resource here (avoiding
the use of internals)

Comment: I think I would have to use PackageManager to get the resources of an external app, since Settings is a separate APK.